# trying to print a sorted dictionary but it gives me syntax error

Tags: python

Looking over some class notes and I came across this piece of code. I copied it exactly from the notes but when i run it, it gives me a syntax error on the final line. Anyone able to point out the mistake?

```
    phone_book = { 'joe' : '086 7346659',
       'jimmy' : '085 2313872',
       'cindy' : '087 9452238' }

    print(sorted(phone_book.items()))
    for k, v in sorted(phone_book.items()):
       print(f' {k} ---> {v}')
```

Comment: What version of Python?  f-strings were introduced in Python 3.6 and would be a syntax error in older versions.  The code works fine in Python 3.9.

Comment: @MarkTolonen yep that was the mistake , I was running 2.7. Thanks for your help

Comment: Try this instead of the last line. print(' {} ---> {}'.format(k, v))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this will help. Your code seems to work fine on python3.7 through python3.9.

Though it doesn't work on 2.7. Try this instead.

```
phone_book = { 'joe' : '086 7346659',
       'jimmy' : '085 2313872',
       'cindy' : '087 9452238' }

print(sorted(phone_book.items()))
for k, v in sorted(phone_book.items()):
    print(k+' ---> '+v)
```

Comment: Answer is better than comments. If you think the comments have valuable info, you can edit that into your answer, so the comments could be deleted.